# c++ library: ensuring that a function is always executed (once) before all others

Tags: c++, wrapper

I am writing a C++ wrapper for a C library. There is an initializer function of the C library that I need to ensure is always executed first before any other function. I want to make it so that the user of my C++ wrapper need not manually do the initialization.

AFAICS one way to ensure this happens is to encapsulate the library functions within a singleton class and have the initializer function executed in the constructor of the class:

```
class Engine {
private:
    static const Engine _instance ;
    Engine() { c_library_initializer() ; }
    // ... prevent copy construction and copy assignment
public:
    static const Engine & handle () const { return _instance ; }
    // ... non-static const wrappers for other c library functions
} ;
```

One minus point to this approach is that it requires some extra coding: within the library for preventing the copying and for the user of the library since all the library methods have to be called via the instance handle:

```
const Engine & lib = Engine::handle() ;
lib.this_function() ;
lib.that_function() ;
```

Another pedantic minus point is that all the wrapper functions are being silently passed a this pointer which is never used. I realize this is not really a big issue with today's memory/processors, but it's there nevertheless IIUC. Perhaps optimizing compilers look for such unused variables and avoid passing them at all? I don't know.

I thought of a simpler approach using an internal class with a single instance within the library's CPP file which would not be visible to the user of my wrapper (and hence does not require copy-protection or returning a handle or calling via that handle):

```
struct EngineInit {
    EngineInit() { c_library_initializer() ; }
} _EngineInit ;
```

The wrapper functions would then just be ordinary (non-member) functions exposed to the user of my wrapper via the H/HPP file.

Do people find any problems with the above method and/or can people suggest any other simpler ways for what I seek to achieve?

Comment: If `c_library_initializer()` has a return value, you could use an anonymous class with one instance instead, and have a private member initialized with the return value of `c_library_initializer()`. That would make it safer for developers using your library.

Comment: Please notice _Uppercase is reserved for the compiler

Comment: Does the C library not "want" to be split into multiple C++ types? For example, if it has `lib_widget_create` and `lib_widget_frob` then you 'd want to have a class `::Lib::Widget`, which makes the singleton entry point approach very bad. I would expect that to be the case most of the time, is it the case here?

Comment: Does the C initializer function have the signature you describe here? No arguments and no (useful) return value? If it takes some kind of context argument, then your wrapper should just be a plain constructor, not a singleton, and each class instance should wrap a single context. But if the C initializer function is global and should only be called once for the entire program (ew), that's not an option

Comment: @jalf: It is not a context like Cairo context etc. It is indeed a single initializer for the whole library. To be more specific, the C library I am wrapping is related to astronomy and before execution of any functions that compute astronomical data (planet positions etc), the location of the JPL ephemeris files needs to be provided to the library.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: AFAICS anonymous classes cannot have user-specified constructors because the constructor is declared by the name of the class. [Ref: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c++.moderated/XqHQqPCXYQk/TJEml5JRQU0J] Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @jamadagni You are correct, and that is why I specified that you would initialize a private member with the return value of `c_library_initializer()` instead of calling it from a constructor (same thing really). You could then wrap the function in a `cpp_library_initializer()` function and throw an exception if there are errors so the user doesn't have to check something like `engine.good()`

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make it so that the user of my C++ wrapper need not manually
>   do the initialization.

This is a bad idea. What if your user decides to use your library from a static variable's constructor? What if you inadvertently do it yourself? Asking the user to initialize a library is a common and sensible practice.

Comment: As a user, it's really horrible when projects try to do this. If your program has startup issues you want to be able to control what is going on.

Comment: @DonReba: Can you please clarify what you mean by "using from a static variable's constructor"?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Actually the c_library_initializer is something that reads a `.ini` file under the user's home directory and does the initialization accordingly. So all one needs to do to control the behaviour is to modify the `.ini` appropriately.

Comment: @jamadagni, what you have in your code sample. Now, imagine another one of those using functions from your library.

Answer (score 1):

If the library doesn't have many functions another approach is to wrap every function in another one that checks if the initialisation was made (using a static variable). You lose some time for the check but you don't need to bother with a singleton.

Comment: Hello. What you say is true but does not really help to reduce code. For every library function I would have to keep checking. If I forget to do so, then the result would not be as expected.

Comment: You'd have to do that anyway as there is no way of guaranteeing that your functions will not be called before the initialization of a static object.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Are you saying that the standard does not guarantee that static objects which are part of a class or library are not necessarily initialized at load up of a program using that library?

Comment: @jamadagni Yes that's correct. In fact you can construct an example where a static object in a class is *always* used before it is constructed (causing UB).

Answer (score 1):

You might use a base class to initialize the library once:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

void c_library_initializer() {
    std::cout << "c_library_initializer\n";
}

class Base
{
    protected:
    Base();
};

Base::Base() {
    static std::once_flag once;
    std::call_once(once, [] { c_library_initializer(); });
}

class Derived : public Base
{};


int main() {
    Derived d0;
    Derived d1;
}
```

Without C++11 you may use boost::call_once: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/doc/html/call_once.html.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can cleanly solve your problem, but there's one thing that came to my mind when reading your question.

You could wrap your library into a shared object (`.so`). That way you could use the `__attribute__((constructor))` on your `c_library_initializer()` function.

> The constructor attribute causes the function to be called automatically before execution enters `main ()`.

Note that this is a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Surely the simple solution is a static constructor?

Declare in your program a non-local static variable of class type, and a constructor for that class will be called to initialise the variable at a very early stage. You can put any code you like in that constructor, such as initialising your C library.

Exactly when the constructor gets called depends on whether it is static or dynamic initialisation, but it will always be before any other code in the same translation unit gets executed.

Or did I miss something?

---

I think this may have been the direction you were heading in your second example, but you didn't go quite far enough. I would write the code something like this.

```
// EngineWrapper.cpp

struct EngineInit {
    EngineInit() { c_library_initializer(); }
};

EngineInit do_not_use; // this static definition triggers initialisation

// Wrapper functions. Note that only wrapper functions contained in this translation unit
// will guarantee to trigger initialisation.
struct EngineWrapper {
    // wrapper 1
    // wrapper 2
};
```

Comment: It seems what you are suggesting is practically the same as the second option I mentioned in my OP. Or is there anything different?

Comment: Very similar. See edit. I was just astonished at the complexity and variety of other solutions proposed for a simple and familiar problem.